# Localhost aliases in Mac OS X mysteriously stopped working

Tags: dns, localhost, alias

For whatever reason aliases for my Mac OS X `localhost` seem to have suddenly stopped working. Presumably follow some update caused this, although I”m not sure what.

Here’s my hosts file:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0 localhost


127.0.0.1 ian.dev
127.0.0.1 d8.dev
```

Despite ian.dev being at 127.0.0.1 here when I debug using `dscacheutil -q host -a name ian.dev` I get:

```
name: ian.dev
ip_address: 127.0.53.53
```

localhost itself is working and I can reach the subfolders within localhost as well, but any new aliases seem to always point out to that IP and not 127.0.0.1.

Comment: It's really just a naming convention. I didn't follow those instructions and update both my hosts files and apache vhosts when I need to.

The .dev aliases were working and work on my other machine with a similar setup but suddenly stopped on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the eventual fix from [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9266686).

Seems my hosts file was corrupted somehow. The series of commands to cleanup the file ended up fixing it:

```
tr '\015' '\012' < /etc/hosts > /tmp/hosts.$$
mv /etc/hosts /etc/hosts.bad
mv /tmp/hosts.$$ /etc/hosts
# fix up permissions while we are at it
chown root:wheel /etc/hosts
chmod 644 /etc/hosts
```

Answer (score 0):

When an IP address returns `127.0.53.53` when there is a potential name collision issue [as described here in the official ICANN documentation](https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/name-collision-2013-12-06-en#127.0.53.53):

> 127.0.53.53 is a special IPv4 address that will appear in system logs alerting system administrators that there is potential name collision
>   issue, enabling a quick diagnosis and remediation. The "53" is used as
>   a mnemonic to indicate a DNS-related problem owing to the use of
>   network port 53 for the DNS service.

Knowing that, I believe the issue comes from you having two entries with `.dev` connected to them; `ian.dev` and `d8.dev`. My thinking is that the DNS resolver on the system see’s the `.dev`, attempt to add `.dev` to the `.local` zone which is the traditional `localhost` “TLD”. And it just chokes for some reason. Or maybe it’s trying to resolve `.dev` in the real world and considers your local setup of `.dev` to be a collision with a real world `.dev` top level domain?

I assume you are doing this for some kind of Apache name based virtual host development on your machine. If so, see what happens if you change these aliases to remove the dot (`.`) so they become this: `ian_dev` and `d8_dev`. Or maybe change them to `ian.local` and d8.local`.

That would be time consuming to adjust your development environment, but I believe it should work.

Barring that, you can do something a bit more invasive on a system level, which might work. The idea comes from [this answer on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/a/626613/100013). Just open up the the DNS `resolv.conf` file like this:

```
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

And add the following `options` line to the bottom of the file:

```
options ndots:2
```

That might work as well. More details [from this site](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-set-dns-search-list-for-host-name-lookup/). Also, as long as you have `resolv.conf`, you might want to check in there to see if there is some other setting in there mucking up the works. For example, here are the contents of my `resolv.conf`:

```
#
# Mac OS X Notice
#
# This file is not used by the host name and address resolution
# or the DNS query routing mechanisms used by most processes on
# this Mac OS X system.
#
# This file is automatically generated.
#
nameserver 208.67.220.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
```

The only two entries I have in there are for OpenDNS namservers. Nothing else. If you have anything more than `nameserver` entries—or maybe not even that much; your config could be empty—then I would recommend commenting out those entries and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but it doesn't seem like either of these is working.

If it isn't .dev then the name is unresolved, but anything .dev even without being in my hosts file resolves to `127.0.53.53`